# Different classpath for maven test and verify?

Tags: java, maven, guava

I can pass my unit in maven test phase, but if I run verify, I will run into NoSuchMethodError issue. I have different guava version in parent pom file and sub module file. But the weird thing is that the test pass in test, but hit this issue in verify. Could anyone let me know why ? Thanks

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
    at org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool.<clinit>(ThreadPool.java:192)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:170)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:140)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:143)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.node(NodeBuilder.java:150)
    ....
```

This is guava related thing in parent pom file

```
 <properties>
   <guava.version>15.0</guava.version>
 </properties>
 <dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>${guava.version}</version>
    </dependency>
 ...
```

And this is guava related thing in sub module

```
  <properties>
    <guava.version>18.0</guava.version>
  </properties>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>${guava.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: You don't provide anything for us to help you. What about some code, some maven dependency? A dependency-tree or something?

Comment: `MoreExecutors.directExecutor()` was introduced in Guava 18.0. You very likely have a version Guava 18+ and another one below that on your classpath. Hashes and stuff doing the rest will make one of the version be taken before another in different contexts, `test` and `verify` being those different contexts.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire What surprise me is that why maven verify would take guava 15 while maven test take guava 18

Comment: This is why a `mvn dependency:tree` can help. Let's imagine the following scenario: parent pom A, children pom B and C. A says "I take Guava 15", B says "I take the same as parent", C says "I take B plus Guava 18" and bam, you have two versions that are needed. As I said, there are hashes and contexts that add more to the classpath. They may at some point put Guava 15 before Guava 18 and do the opposite in an other context. To avoid your issue, just check the dependency tree then remove unwanted Guava versions from your child by using `<exclusions>...</exclusions>`.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire `dependency:tree` shows I get the guava 18 which is correct and test phase is passed, but when I run `mvn verify`, the test fails, very weird, it seems `verify phase` would take guava 15 while `test phase` would take guava 18

Comment: What version of Maven do you use? How many versions of Guava do you see in `mvn dependency:tree`? How/where do you run `mvn verify` and `mvn test`? Can you create a Maven [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that uses the method `MoreExecutors.directExecutor()` in one of the tests? You give practically no information for us to help you. You should be much, much more exhaustive in your question and details.